# What is post_max_size in php?

Tags: php

Im actually confused both upload_max_size and post_max_size.

I searched on the google. but all the results show about how to increase size. but my question is what is post_max_size.

Comment: try `echo ini_get('post_max_size');` https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ini-get.php https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size

Answer (score -1, accepted):

#### Post_max_size

Sets max size of post data allowed. This setting also affects file upload. To upload large files, this value must be larger than upload_max_filesize.

Generally speaking, memory_limit should be larger than post_max_size. When an int is used, the value is measured in bytes. Shorthand notation, as described in this FAQ, may also be used. If the size of post data is greater than post_max_size, the $_POST and $_FILES superglobals are empty.

This can be tracked in various ways, e.g. by passing the $_GET variable to the script processing the data, i.e. , and then checking if $_GET['processed'] is set.

[Just literately from PHP.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size)

Comment: **Not** my downvote, but if you are just going to reproduce parts of a manual, it would be better to make a comment and add a link to the manual page.

Comment: Furthermore, there is no point is posting an answer if you've already cast a close vote

Comment: @DarkBee I answered before I saw the duplicate question..

Comment: @RiggsFolly I think this is hard, because another guideline is not just to post links to another site for the answer. And the text was bit much for a comment. I guess it's a bad example because the question itself didn't meet the community guidelines.

Comment: You could still delete the answer afterwards...

Comment: You also ___voted to close the question, but still answered it___ Thus stopping Roomba from removal of the question

Comment: @RiggsFolly, as I said in an other comment. I answered it, saw a duplicate question posted by someone else, also voted to close. The only reason I haven't deleted this yet is because it's still active :) Without your comment and Tommy his comments, I would already deleted this.

Comment: Also I did suggest ___making a comment___ and including a link, not just putting a link in a comment

Comment: You cant now that the OP has accepted it :)

Comment: Like I said in my previous comment, the text was a bit much too post it as a comment. This discussion is getting way offtopic. Let's just be glad we helped one person and only annoyed two :)

Comment: Ha, not annoyed, just trying to do my curation duties to SO practices. _Note_ you would not have had to reproduce the whole text in the comment, just say something like "There is some information about this [in the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size)"

Answer (score -1):

According to official PHP manual:

> Sets max size of post data allowed. This setting also affects file
> upload. To upload large files, this value must be larger than
> upload_max_filesize. Generally speaking, memory_limit should be larger
> than post_max_size. When an int is used, the value is measured in
> bytes. Shorthand notation, as described in this FAQ, may also be used.
> If the size of post data is greater than post_max_size, the $_POST and
> $_FILES superglobals are empty. This can be tracked in various ways,
> e.g. by passing the $_GET variable to the script processing the data,
> i.e. , and then checking if
> $_GET['processed'] is set.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size

Comment: Beat you to it :p

Comment: **Not** my downvote, but if you are just going to reproduce parts of a manual, it would be better to make a comment and add a link to the manual page.